# How to Modify property / attributes of others using admin or authorised credentials in Active Directory in c#

Tags: c#, .net

How to Modify property or attributes of others users using admin or authorised credentials in Active Directory in c#

below is the code which i'm trying to use.

```
        string username = "Test User";
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(CreateDirectoryEntry())
            {
                Filter = $"(cn={username})"
            };
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("title");

            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            if (result != null)
            {
                // create new object from search result
                DirectoryEntry entryToUpdate = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

                // show existing title  
                Console.WriteLine($"Current title   : {entryToUpdate.Properties["title"][0]}");

                Console.Write("\n\nEnter new title : ");

                // get new title and write to AD  
                string newTitle = Console.ReadLine();
                entryToUpdate.Properties["title"].Value = newTitle;
                entryToUpdate.CommitChanges();

                Console.WriteLine("\n\n...new title saved");
            }
```

Comment: Try powershell instead : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/set-localuser?view=powershell-5.1